# Is the inverse of the canonical homomorphism a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f:G \to G/K$ be the canonical homomorphism where $K$ is a subgroup of the group $G.$ 
Is $f^{-1}: G/K \to G$ a homomorphism as well? K is normal.

Comment: First, in general $\;f^{-1}\;$ is not even a well-defined function, so you *first* will have to choose representatives of the (left-right) cosets, and hope things will go fine. It's not trivial, but you can find things like this one in split exact sequences, say.

Comment: If K is normal?

Comment: @Meitar: After 25 questions, you should seriously learn MathJax. here is a link: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I try to. I do. But my internet is in Hebrew and it causes troubles... I am sorry

Comment: If $K$ is not normal then $G/K$ has no group structure. What did you mean by "canonical homomorphism", if $K$ is not normal?

Comment: @Meitar Of course that "if $\;K\;$ is normal", otherwise the quotient group $\;G/K\;$ doesn't exists and, obviously, there is no "canonical homomorphis".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $G = \mathbb Z, K = 2\mathbb Z.$ Now $G/K = \mathbb Z_2.$ Suppose we have a group homomorphism $\phi: G/K \to G.$ Then what will be $\phi(\bar 1)$?

Note that $2 \phi(\bar 1) = \phi(2 \cdot \bar 1) = \phi (\bar 0) = 0.$ So $\phi(\bar 1) = 0.$ Thus the only possible choice for $\phi$ is that it's a zero homomorphism.

Comment: Great answer... 
But that mean I cannot build such a homomorphism and have to solve my problem in another way. Thank you.